# how to expand sum column using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have table like this:
df:

```
  A B C D
0 1 1 0 7
1 1 1 0 9
2 1 1 1 5
3 1 1 1 3
```

After doing `df.groupby(['A','B','C']).sum()` i get:

```
  A B C D
0 1 1 0 16
1 1 1 1 8
```

By what method I can get

```
  A B C D
0 1 1 0 16
1 1 1 0 16
2 1 1 1 8
3 1 1 1 8
```

which will not aggregate the original rows while getting the sum column??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation): it does the aggregation but returns an object indexed the same way as the original.

```
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  7
1  1  1  0  9
2  1  1  1  5
3  1  1  1  3
>>> df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"]).transform('sum')
    D
0  16
1  16
2   8
3   8
>>> df["D"] = df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"]).transform('sum')
>>> df 
   A  B  C   D
0  1  1  0  16
1  1  1  0  16
2  1  1  1   8
3  1  1  1   8
```